# Texts in a container not shown horizontally, any suggestion?

Tags: html, css

I was trying to get this text in a button container shown horizontally (likewise the way we are seeing on books or webpage), but even after I add horizontal-tb it still shown vertically, which makes it hard to read. Here is my code:

```css
.backButton {
    display: flex;  
    justify-content: center;  
    align-items: center; 
    text-align: center; 
    writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important; 
    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 20px; 
    right: 20px; 
    width: 60px !important; 
    height: 60px !important; 
    border-radius: 50%; 
    background-color: pink; 
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px; 
    z-index: 9999; 
}
```

Is there any other thing I can try or do I need to check other part of the code to solve this issue?

Comment: You need to provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: [mre], please, when you ask this kind of question - and not just snippets that lack context.